# Find dict by two values

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

`able` is a list of tuples and `beta` is a list of dicts. `able` and `beta` have the same number of elements. Order is not guaranteed.

Given an `able`, find the dict in `beta` where the value of `beta[10]` equals `able[0]` and value of `beta[20]` equals `able[1]`.

There will always be a unique match.

The following works, but there has to be a better way. I just can't figure out what it is.

```
able = [(1,2), (3,4), (1,4), (3,5)]
beta = [{10:1, 20:2, 30:3}, {10:3, 20:4, 30:55}, {10:3, 20:5, 30:66}, {10:1, 20:4, 30:11}]

for a in able:
    for b in beta:
        if a[0] == b[10] and a[1] == b[20]:
            print(b)
            break
```

I suppose I could sort both `able` and `beta`. Then the Nth `able` would correspond to the Nth `beta`, so determine the index of the given `able` and report the `beta` with that index. This doesn't seem much better or more pythonic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generate a dictionary with keys that correspond to the values you want to find:

```
beta2 = {(b[10], b[20]): b for b in beta}
print([beta2[a] for a in able])
```